# How do I make eclipse xsd/xml content assist show annotations from xsd?

Tags: eclipse, xsd, content-assist

XML validates just fine. Content Assist shows the valid elements. The problem is that I want to document each of the elements/attributes, but that annotations are not displayed in the content assist. Is this possible, or should I stew and rely on my dreams to provide the satisfaction I'm looking for?